# hsqldb - no sync between applications

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, jndi, hsqldb

I use a datasource (directing to a file-based hsqldb) from two applications in parallel and in one of them I edit an entry (no matter if I use `commit` or `checkpoint` as sql commands), **my other application don't realise this change until I restart the other application**.

I am using

- apache-tomcat-8.0.26
- org.hsqldb.hsqldb 2.3.3

Within the `apache-tomcat-8.0.26/conf/context.xml` file I've defined a resource named `jdbc/xyz` of type `javax.sql.DataSource` to my file-based hsqldb (url: `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/myfolder/mydatabase;shutdown=true;hsqldb.lock_file=false`).

If I use this datasource only from one application deployed on the tomcat server and do the editing I have no problems.

Do you have any ideas what the reason for this strange behaviour could be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: currently I suspect the parameter `shutdown=true` to be the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a single java process can access a jdbc:hsqldb:file database. You need to start an HSQLDB Server. The server can be started in the process that runs Tomcat. You can then connect to this server with jdbc:hsqldb:hsql: protocol.

Comment: You can access a `jdbc:hsqldb:file` database from different java processes in parallel but without any synchronisation. The *updates*, *inserts*, *deletes*, *alters* are written to the hsqldb-log file and if no problem occurs, you may have all changes after the next restart with `hsqldb.full_log_replay=true` but this is surely not guaranteed and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: NO. The lock file disallows parallel access.

Comment: Not if you use `hsqldb.lock_file=false` as I descride in my original post.